# How to load AWS SDK into CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk

I'm creating a S3 plugin for my app. In `app/Plugin/S3/Controller/Component/S3Component.php` I have these:

```
<?php 

App::import('Vendor', 'aws/aws-autoloader');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class S3Component extends Component {

    public function loadS3 () {
        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key' => '',
            'secret' => ''
        ));
        return $s3;
    }

}
```

In my app's controller, I call it using `$s3 = $this->S3->loadS3();`

It throws the error `Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found`

I tried adding the line: `App::uses('Vendor', 'aws/Aws/S3/S3Client');` to the component class, and removed `use Aws\S3\S3Client;`. It shows `Error: Class 'S3Client' not found`

The AWS SDK in in the folder `app/Plugin/S3/Vendor/aws`

I'm loading the S3 object with reference to: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html#factory-method

**Solution:**

This is how my component looks like now with the help of @akirk.

```
<?php 

ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'). PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT .DS . 'app/Plugin/S3/Vendor/aws');

require ROOT . DS . 'app/Plugin/S3/Vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class S3Component extends Component {

    public function loadS3 () {
        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key' => '',
            'secret' => ''
        ));
        return $s3;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. above solution not working for me..
I am using same folder structure. and followed https://github.com/Ali1/cakephp-amazon-aws-sdk
can you tell me is it right or not?

Comment: It is version issue.. I am using SDK V3

Comment: Not working with SDK V2,8 . can you please help me. here is the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052772/class-aws-common-aws-not-found-cakephp

Comment: @urfusion I think your aws sdk is stored in a different location from mine. You might want to check your path and tweak the `ini_set` and `require` paths accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the autoimport doesn't work. You should do it as in the tutorial, use `require`

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

as the autoloading mechanism shouldn't be touched by CakePHP.