# Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS PHP SDK V2.8 in my cakephp. I am working on AWS ec2 ubuntu machine.

> I use zip files not any composer.

I am getting following error.

```
Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found
```

I create a custom component for accessing all features of SDK. with the reference of https://github.com/Ali1/cakephp-amazon-aws-sdk

My folder structure is as follows

[image]

Here is my AmazonComponent.php

```
<?php

App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
use Aws\Common\Aws;

/**
 * AmazonComponent
 *
 * Provides an entry point into the Amazon SDK.
 */
class AmazonComponent extends Component {

  /**
   * Constructor
   * saves the controller reference for later use
   * @param ComponentCollection $collection A ComponentCollection this component can use to lazy load its components
   * @param array $settings Array of configuration settings.
   */
  public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
    $this->_controller = $collection->getController();
    parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
  }

  /**
   * Initialization method. Triggered before the controller's `beforeFilfer`
   * method but after the model instantiation.
   *
   * @param Controller $controller
   * @param array $settings
   * @return null
   * @access public
   */
  public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
    // Handle loading our library firstly...
      $this->Aws = Aws::factory(Configure::read('Amazonsdk.credentials'));
  }

  /**
   * PHP magic method for satisfying requests for undefined variables. We
   * will attempt to determine the service that the user is requesting and
   * start it up for them.
   *
   * @var string $variable
   * @return mixed
   * @access public
   */
  public function __get($variable) {
    $this->$variable = $this->Aws->get($variable);
    return $this->$variable;
  }
}
```

I add these two line on the top on file with the reference of this question 
[How to load AWS SDK into CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778202/how-to-load-aws-sdk-into-cakephp)

```
ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'). PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT .DS . 'app/Plugin/Amazonsdk/Vendor/aws');

require ROOT . DS . 'app/Plugin/Amazonsdk/Vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
```

Where I am wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

@urfusion Could you pls move AWS SDK folder from `app/Plugin` to `app/Vendor` In Side the app/Vendor And then try to import aws-sdk `AmazonComponent` having Function `initialize`.

I am using AWS PHP SDK V3

// Handle loading our library firstly...

```
 App::import('Vendor','aws-autoloader',array('file'=>'aws'.DS.'aws-autoloader.php'));
```